# Plot with ggrepel labels renders very slowly

Tags: r, performance, ggplot2, rendering, ggrepel

I've got a `ggplot` graphic with `ggrepel` labels that renders in a few seconds on my local quad-core laptop. However, when I attempt to render this same graphic on a server with 32 cores (or even 96 cores), the server requires over 10 minutes.

Why is `ggrepel` rendering so slowly?

From what I understand, `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` assigns a repulsive force or charge to each label. Does this type of computation require a physics engine that runs much faster on a GPU? I believe the servers I am using do not have GPUs, and are processing the repulsion on a single CPU core.

Comment: How many labels are we talking about?

Comment: ~400 labels in the plot

Comment: This doesn't directly address the rendering, but are 400 labels both necessary and legible?

Comment: Necessary and while I can’t share there is no issue of legibility